# To get value of textbox

Tags: javascript, asp.net

In the below code I have a textbox and I am binding the textbox to a datalist. So now there are four textboxes. My actual aim is to get the values of all 4 textboxes but I can get only one value of one textbox. Please help me to solve the issue.
Js:

```
function check(){
    var value = document.getElementById("<%= txtField.ClientID %>").value;
    alert(value);//
}
```

asp.net:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtField" runat="server" width="200Px"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: Css Ids must be unique. You can instead use class

Comment: @ Nitin Varpe All the 4 values are in textbox i want to get all values but i can get 1 value.

Comment: what do u mean by all 4 values are in textbox?. can u create fiddle

Comment: Yep. I supposed he can depict it using pure html @Satpal

Comment: You can do this by code behind by using ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ClientID` will fire only for a Particular `Textbox` of First match found only. You should have written some `Jquery` for it. 
Try it

```
str = "";
$('input[type=text]').each(function (){
   str+=$(this).val() + "$";
  });
if(str != "")
  str = str.substring(0,str.length-1);

alert(str);
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9DW5X/)

**Explanation :**

`input[type=text]` selector  will work for every `input` control of `DOM`  which is of `Text`  type. [`.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) function of [`jQuery`](http://jquery.com/) will iterate through all the textboxes of DOM and concates in `str` . And after completion of iteration its showing all concatenated values using [`alert`](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp) 
`$(this).val()` will pull out values of all textboxes found in that context.

Comment: i have a hidden field <asp:HiddenField ID="hidRegExp" runat="server" >
</asp:HiddenField > and i want to get all the values from it by spliting value .i tried by using input[type=hidden] but i cant get any value.

Comment: It  should work with hidden field too in same way...You must be doing something wrong..